# node-webkit WritableStream doesn't flush until close()

Tags: node.js, flush, node-webkit, fs

I'm saving some data inside an http.get in node-webkit on a Mac. I noticed that the target filesize stays at 0 bytes in Finder until the file is closed.

I can setup a ReadableStream and read from the file I'm just writing to and the data is there, so I'm guessing it's buffered in memory or something ... which is bad, because I'm downloading large files.

Any ideas how to force it to flush to the file regularly?

Below is roughly what I'm trying:

```
var file_options = { flags: 'w', encoding: null, mode: 0666 };
var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, file_options);

var get_options = {
    host: parsedUrl.host || parsedUrl.hostname,
    port: parsedUrl.port,
    path: parsedUrl.pathname + search,
    headers: {Range: "bytes="+offset+"-"+limit},
    agent: false
};

var request = http.get(get_options, function (response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var ready = file.write(chunk, encoding='binary');
        if (ready === false) {
            this.pause();
            file.once('drain', this.resume.bind(this));
            console.log('flushed');
        }
    });
});
```

It only seems to get backed-up and need to pause every once in a while ... so why aren't I seeing the filesize or last-modified change?
If I close the app whilst it's downloading before closing the stream it updates at that point, so I'm wondering if it's something that's happening in the Mac kernel itself and not in node-webkit.

Comment: Many platforms don't update the directory entry until the file is closed.

Comment: yes I think you're right ... it doesn't seem to affect how I can use the file, just how we're observing it in the OS.